# computing standard deviation in R and in Python

Tags: python, r

Does Python and R have different ways to compute the standard deviation (sd)?

For example, in python, starting with :

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],  [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

print(a.std(axis=1)) 
### per row : [0.81649658 0.81649658 0.81649658]

print(a.std(axis=0)) 
### per column : [2.44948974 2.44948974 2.44948974]
```

While in R :

```
z <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=T)

# z
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 1 2 3
#[2,] 4 5 6
#[3,] 7 8 9

# apply(z, 1, sd)
sd(z[1,]) #1
sd(z[2,]) #1
sd(z[3,]) #1

# apply(z, 2, sd)
sd(z[,1]) #3
sd(z[,2]) #3
sd(z[,3]) #3
```

Answer (score 7):

It's because `sd()` from `base-R` uses by default `n-1` in the formula for the denominator ([docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.0/topics/sd)).

`numpy` instead uses `n` by default, but you can use `ddof` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)) to specify the `n-1` correction.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],  [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print(a.std(axis=1, ddof = 1)) 
[1. 1. 1.]
```

Basically, the `mean` part can be calculated using  [image: 1/n]  or  [image: 1/n-1] .

Note that the difference between the two methods is small if `n` is big. In the example this is pretty evident because `n=3`, try with `n=1000` and see the difference.

Further [readings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) on why the `n-1` correction is used.